# PUT Request not Updating data-Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using Postman to get my request. My GET and POST appear to be working fine. It's only when I go to update the data with PUT that its where I am running into the hiccup. Postman actually sends data back as if the object is being updated, but when I go to check via GET it's the same data as before. I have tried adding the hive data to the serializer.save, but it tells me I'm adding too many parameters.

**models.py**

```py
class Inspection(models.Model):
     hive = models.ForeignKey(Hive, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     eggs = models.IntegerField()
     larvae = models.IntegerField()
     sealed_brood = models.IntegerField()
     covered_bees = models.IntegerField()
     nectar_honey = models.IntegerField()
     pollen = models.IntegerField()
     pest_spotted = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     pest_action = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     notes_concerns = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class InspectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Inspection
        fields = ['id', 'eggs', 'larvae', 'sealed_brood', 'covered_bees', 'nectar_honey', 'nectar_honey', 'pollen', 'pest_spotted', 'pest_action', 'notes_concerns','user_id','hive','hive_id']
        depth = 1

    hive_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
```

Views.py

```py
@api_view(['GET', 'POST','PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def inspection_details(request, pk):
    hive = get_object_or_404(Hive, pk=pk)
    inspection = Inspection.objects.filter(hive_id = hive.id, user=request.user)
    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = InspectionSerializer(inspection, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = InspectionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(user=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data,status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = InspectionSerializer(hive, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(user=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: In the put clause, why is hive passed as the instance in the `InspectionSerializer`?

Comment: It has a FK to it.

Comment: POST and GET are working fine

Comment: Yeah get works because you use `inspection` as the instance. In the put try to use something like `InspectionSerializer(inspection.first(), data=request.data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the instance variable is not correct, it should be `inspection` not `hive`.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def inspection_details(request, pk):
    hive = get_object_or_404(Hive, pk=pk)
    inspection = Inspection.objects.filter(hive_id = hive.id, user=request.user)
    ...
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = InspectionSerializer(inspection, data=request.data)   # here
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(user=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use if clause for is_valid. it raise exception anyway so if is not needed.

Next you need to update your serializer not saving it.

```
 elif request.method == 'PUT':
    serializer = InspectionSerializer(hive, data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.update(object_to_update,serializer.validated_data)
    # if you want to return updated serialized data :
    updated_serializer = InspectionSerializer(object_to_update)
    return Response(updated_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```